# How to design game loop for a terminal based card game in Javascript and Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, terminal, game-development

I'm trying to make a turn based card game in Javascript and Node.js in which the player plays against the computer on the terminal. I'm confused on how to implement the game loop for it. After each of computer's turn the player has some options like viewing their cards or choosing one of their cards .The issues i'm facing is
that how do i run an interactive session on terminal so that the player makes some choices for their turn and the game loop waits for it. Then the computer plays its turn and this goes on. I don't want the game session to end after someone presses enter after their move. I don't wanna use databses for it.

It should happen like this-

```
> Player's turn
> view_cards
> cards = ["4 of clubs", "3 of spades", "ace of spades", "red king", "10 of spades"]
> select cards[2]
> Player selected "ace of spades"
> Computer's turn
> computer selected "2 of hearts"
......
```

How do i achieve this without the game ending when someone presses enter.